# Height and Width with a menu

Tags: c#, wpf

```
                    <Menu Height="50" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
                        <Menu.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,0" StartPoint="0,1">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFB3DDF2" Offset="1.0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFD6E9F4" Offset="0.0"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Menu.Background>
                    </Menu>
```

This Menu will stretch no matter how long the page is and doesn't need to have a width.

```
                    <Menu Width="350" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
                        <Menu.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,0" StartPoint="0,1">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFD6E9F4" Offset="1.0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.0"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Menu.Background>
                    </Menu>
```

I want to do the same with this menu however it requires a height which means if i stretch the page down, the menu size will not stretch with the page. When I don't put a height into the code no menu bar appears. My question is how come I don't need a width for the menu bar but i need a height.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

It is by design.

A menu ***bar*** is something that is assumed to stretch across the control it is contained in.  That's why it doesn't need a width.

It needs a height because you can put any content inside it.

A stretch height wouldn't have a whole lot of meaning for a menu control, since it'd just be a large blank area of its background color, if WPF were to draw it for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is there another control which acts like a menu which I could use so I don't need a fixed height?